# Sharepoint 2013 page layout putting site name on title problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, design-manager

I made a page layout in design manager in sharepoint 2013. When I create a page with that page layout, and then when I view the page, the title (big text under the ribbon) is a combination of two things. For some reason it prepends the site name to the title field when not in edit mode. For example if the site name is `test2` and then the title field is `helloWorld`, then when I view the page not in edit mode, the title says `test2 helloWorld`.... And note that I didn't customize the page layout, I just created a new one. If I change the page layout back to any OOTB one, then the problem does not occur. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a custom page layout, the following block of code is added to you page:

```
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">-->
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span id="ctl00_DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">Home</span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
        <!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>-->
        <!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
        <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>-->
        <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"%>-->
        <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
        <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

You need to remove the block of code for SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb so that the block now looks as follows:

```
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->           
        <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"%>-->
        <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
        <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```